# Lead statement not correct

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use a lead statement to use a start date of a new date as the previous end date

```
Name_id        Pay      Start 
John1          $10      01-01-2011
John1          $11      01-05-2012
John1          $15      01-06-2014
```

What I want is:

```
Name_id        Pay      Start           End 
John1          $10      01-01-2011      01-05-2012
John1          $11      01-05-2012      01-06-2014
John1          $15      01-06-2014      NULL
```

I've tried

`select name_id, start as start, LEAD(start, 1,0 ) over(order by date) as end`

but I get

```
Name_id        Pay      Start           End 
John1          $10      01-01-2011      04-01-2011 //Random date??
John1          $11      01-05-2012       01-05-2012  
John1          $15      01-06-2014      01-06-2014
```

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) -- I noticed that every date you have used makes the date format ambiguous.

Comment: what is "date" field in (order by date) ??

Answer (score 0):

You have the order by wrong I believe.  It should be:

```
select name_id, start as start, LEAD(start, 1,0 ) over(order by start) as end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should fail. I assume your order by date is actually order by start and you bracketed out your end column name as end is a key word and throws incorrect syntax. Other than that, your LEAD offset should be LEAD(start, 1, start). The syntax is LEAD ( scalar_expression [ ,offset ] , [ default ] ). Please see the [lead documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql). You probably also want to partition by Name_id assuming you have multiple names and don't want your start date of one name to be the end name of the other.

Here is the table variable I made to test.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    Name_id NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Pay INT,
    [Start] DATE
)

INSERT @tbl VALUES 
('John1',10,'01-01-2011'),
('John1',11,'01-05-2012'),
('John1',15,'01-06-2014')
```

Here is the query I ran to test.

```
SELECT
    [Name_id],
    [Pay],
    [Start],
    LEAD([Start], 1, [Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY Name_id ORDER BY [Start]) AS [End]
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of misleading stuff in your question.

I just removed the offset and default from LEAD and it worked as expected. Your sample query is wrong and has syntax error.

```
create table #tt (
Name_id varchar(10), Pay int, [Start] date
)

insert into #tt values
('John1', 10, '01-01-2011'),
('John1', 11, '01-05-2012'),
('John1', 15, '01-06-2014')

select Name_id, Pay, Start, LEAD([Start]) over(order by [Start]) as [End]
from #tt
```

You can not say LEAD(Start, 1, 0) because `default` should be a date and you have provided a 0 which is a number

Per your desired output you even don't need to specify the `offset` and `default`.